Showing outer measure for compact sets need only finite covers in definition
Let $m^*(E)$ denote the Lebesgue outer measure of $E \subset \mathbb{R}$. I want to prove that for a compact set $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ we have:
$$ m^*(E) = \text{Inf} \{ \sum_{n=1}^N l(I_n) \mid E \subseteq \cup_{n=1}^N I_n, \text{ $I_n$ are open bounded intervals of finite length}  \} $$
My attempt:
Start with $m^*(E) = \text{Inf} \{ m(O) \mid E \subseteq O , \text{ $O$ is open subset} \}$. Now every open set can be written as countable union of open disjoint intervals $\{I_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and so by compactness:
$$ m^*(E) = \text{Inf} \{ \sum_{n=1}^\infty l(I_n) \mid E \subseteq \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} I_n  \} = \text{Inf} \{ \sum_{n=1}^N l(I_n) \mid E \subseteq \cup_{n=1}^N I_n  \} $$
Can you please verify if my proof is right? If it is not right please help me on how to get a proof for this, if it is right please suggest me some other ways to prove the same.
Any help is highly appreciated.

The idea of your argument is correct but if I were you I would rather prove the two inequalities instead of dealing directly with the equality. Here is a way of doing it:
Any finite union of open sets being open, the first inequality is straightforward
$$m^*(E) = \inf \left\{m(O) \mid E \subseteq O , \text{ $O$ is open} \right\} \le \inf\left\{ \sum_{n=1}^N \ell(I_n) \mid E \subseteq \cup_{n=1}^N I_n   \right\}.$$
For the other inequality, consider $O$ open containing $E$ and, as you said, there exists a countable sequence of disjoint intervals $(I_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ such that
$$E \subseteq O = \bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty I_n.$$
By compactness of $E$, one can extract a finite number of $I_n$ satisfying
$$E \subset \bigcup_{n = 1}^N I_n,$$
and by monotonicity, we deduce
$$m\left(\bigcup_{n = 1}^NI_n\right) = \sum_{n = 1}^N \ell(I_n) \le m(O).$$
Therefore,
$$\inf\left\{ \sum_{n=1}^N \ell(I_n) \mid E \subseteq \cup_{n=1}^N I_n   \right\} \le m(O), \quad \forall ~O \text{ open and containing }E.$$
Taking the infimum on the righthand side gives you the other inequality and concludes.
